# mochapack --watch fails with "runnable.enableTimeouts is not a function" when VSCode autosaves

Tags: visual-studio-code, mochapack

We recently introduced `mochapack --watch` into our testing process

`cross-env NODE_ENV=development mochapack --watch --require tests/components/setup.ts \"tests/components/**/*.spec.ts\"`

My VSCode instance has autosave turned on. After about two or three editing cycles, mochapack reliably fails with this error:

```
C:\Users\me\git\terraforming-mars\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:962
    throw err;
    ^

TypeError: runnable.enableTimeouts is not a function
    at C:\Users\me\git\terraforming-mars\node_modules\mochapack\src\runner\TestRunner.ts:217:20
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\me\git\terraforming-mars\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:22:1)
    at run (C:\Users\me\git\terraforming-mars\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:142:33)
    at C:\Users\me\git\terraforming-mars\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:129:6
    at C:\Users\me\git\terraforming-mars\node_modules\webpack\lib\HookWebpackError.js:68:3
    ...
```

When I turn it off, my workflow is just fine.

Obviously I can disable autosave for now, but does anyone have a good combined configuration of  mochapack --watch and autosave that work well together?

Comment: So it seems saving the file repeatedly has the same effect as auto-saving. mochapack doesn't seem to like when I save while it's churning through a compile/pack phase.